# Create new tab from Firefox extension doesn't works

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

i'm trying to create a new tab from Firefox extension, but it doesn't works.

manifest.js:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "nafy",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "NaFy",

  "icons": {
  "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
  "96": "icons/icon_96.png"
  },
  
  "content_scripts": [
   {
        "matches": ["*://*.ebay.de/*"],
        "js": ["background.js"]
   }
  ],
  
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```js
createNewTab();


function onCreated(tab) {
    console.log('Created new tab: ${tab.id}');
}

function onError(error) {
    console.log('Error: ${error}');
}

function createNewTab()
{
    let newTab = browser.tabs.create({
         url:"https://www.ebay.de"
    });
    newTab.then(onCreated, onError);
};
```

What I'm doing wrong? (Everything works as expected in Chrome.)

Comment: This is not a background script, this is a content script, which isn't allowed to use `tabs` API. In content script you can use window.open. You can also send a message to your real background script declared in `background` section of manifest.json, and then the real backgournd script can use browser.tabs.create.

Answer (score 1):

Your `background.js` file is not actually a background script despite it's name, it's defined in your `manifest.json` as a content script.

Content scripts don't have access to the [tabs API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs) ([see list of accessible APIs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#webextension_apis)).

To fix that, you need to move your `background.js` to be an actual background script:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "nafy",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "NaFy",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
    "96": "icons/icon_96.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```